# Jackson Deserializer not being called for @*Param

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

Im trying to use JsonDeserialzer on a jax path parameter.

Here is my @BeanParam object,

```
@BeanParam
private CustomerWrapper reference;

@QueryParam("select")
private String select;

@QueryParam("count")
private boolean count;



@BeanParam
PaginationInfo paginationInfo;

@BeanParam
private SortingInfo sortingInfo;

@QueryParam("line")
private String line;

@QueryParam("typeCode")
private String typeCode;

class CustomReference {
  @NotNull
  @PathParam("profileReferenceId")
  @Encoded
  private String referenceId;

  public CustomerReference(String referenceId) {
     this.referenceId = referenceId;
  }

  public CustomeReference fromString() {
     return new CustomerReference(Base64.decode(referenceId));
  }
}
```

The `referenceId` field is a base64 encoded string, to decode it, i am using a jsondeserializer.

However, i have read json messagereader does not work on jax @*params.

From another post, i figured this can be achieved by creating `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider`.

```
Example,

@Provider
public class TestClass implements ParamConverterProvider {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestClass.class);

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(
            Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] antns) {

        logger.debug("rawtype " +rawType.getName());
        for(Annotation a : antns) {
            logger.debug("anotations " +a.annotationType().getName());
        }

        return null;
    }
}


output:
[DEBUG] 31 Oct 2016 23:20:23,788 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-1] TestClass - rawtype boolean
[DEBUG] 31 Oct 2016 23:20:23,788 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-1] TestClass - anotations javax.ws.rs.QueryParam
```

**why does this converter only recognize one queryparam and ignore the rest.**

Comment: The param converter is only used for custom types. Primitives like String and boolean are already handle by Jersey.

Comment: @peeskillet ah i see. any recommended suggestion to hack the behavior of jsondeserialize on the pathparam?

Comment: You just create a custom wrapper type around the string property, and add a `public static YourType fromString(String param)` in the class. In that method you can return `new YourType(Base64.decode(param))`. Jersey has a `Base64` class you can use. Jersey will call the `fromString` method

Comment: @peeskillet i edited the question. is this what you meant? Also, do i have to still include the ParamConverterProvider

Comment: More like [this](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/5eab6f369d20ad8b8acf9db36d1c3211). And no you don't need the param converter.

Comment: @peeskillet awesome thanks so much. i approached the problem wrong to begin with. i faintly remembered reading 
In general the Java type of the method parameter may:
 "Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument" as part of the jersey documentation.