# JAX-RS, how to replace a queryParam value

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

So I have to create a filter that adds/formats  date strings.

My implementation was to create a `ContainerRequestFilter` and perform formatting there; then add this custom filter through `@NameBinding`.

My problem seems to be that `@NameBinding` is ignored when used with `@PreMatching`, thus not being able to work since I also use reflection to extract properties from my filter/annotation.

So after performing formatting in filter, the idea is to use:

```
uriBuilder.replaceQueryParam(startDateQueryParamName, formattedString);
```

but even if I add a **hardcoded** value, the value is still the original.

Say I make a request:   `.../api/x?startDate=1234-01-01T00:00:00`

And I hardcode in filter:

```
`uriBuilder.replaceQueryParam(startDateQueryParamName, "2020-05-05T00:00:00");`
```

I still get `1234-01-01T00:00:00` in resource method:

```
@GET
@Path("/t1")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@StartEndDateFilter(required = true)
public String testLocalDateTime(@QueryParam("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate, @QueryParam("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate, @Context UriInfo urinfo) {

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> m = urinfo.getQueryParameters();        
    String d = startDate == null ? "nothin " : startDate.toString();
    String e = endDate == null ? "nothin " : endDate.toString();

    return String.format("start: %s \nend:  %s", d, e);
}
```

So, I thought maybe using `@PreMatching` would help  but, as I mentioned, this shows a warning:

> Warning:   @PreMatching provider, class com.api.DateRangeFilter, also
>   annotated with a name binding annotation. Name binding will be
>   ignored.

And on top of that, when I call `requestContext.setRequestUri(uriBuilder.build());` I get the following error when I call the endpoint:

> Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.api.Ap]: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet com.api.Ap threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Method could be called only in pre-matching request filter.   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.setRequestUri(ContainerRequest.java:411)
>     at com.api.DateRangeFilter.filter(DateRangeFilter.java:153)

line 153 is:

```
requestContext.setRequestUri(uriBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Maybe you can do it in a `ParamConverter`. [See example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31627624/2587435)

Comment: Nope, ParamConverters are for a different purpose

Comment: My point is that what you're trying to do is not possible. So you will need to find another way.

Comment: Maybe even some kind of hack. It's just not meant to work this way, as you want to access the selected resource method before it's selected, and you can't change anything about the URI after it's been selected. So you need to look for another way to get the results you want

Comment: How did you finally solve it ? I am having the exact same problem!!

Comment: @Ajay  I used a ContainerRequestFilter  with `@PreMatching` annotation and this made the filter global and applies before actual resource matching occurs.