# @JsonFormat for date parsing in JAX-RS service is ignored

Tags: java, rest, date, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to pass a date to a JAX-RS service. Checking other questions like: [Date format Mapping to JSON Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson)

The answers and the documentation show that there is a [jackson annotation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling) which should allow date formatting.

```
public class SolutionFilter {
    @MatrixParam("toDate")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", timezone="CET")
    private Date toDate;

    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }
}
```

Upon calling the Rest-Service I'm getting a `ParseException`:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-01-01"
  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpDateFormat.readDate(HttpDateFormat.java:137)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverters$DateProvider$1.fromString(ParamConverters.java:259)
```

It seems like the annotation is ignored. Debugging the parse method the pattern is set to `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz` and `EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy`.

I'm using Spring 4.2.1, Jersey 2.22 which binds jackson 2.5.4.

How can I get the dates parsed with the correct pattern?

**Update:** Thinking further about it the JSON is only used for output parsing. But this is probably about JAX-RS parameter parsing.

Comment: why cant you just accept the `date` as `string` and do parse it later in your code..

Comment: @SajanChandran that would indeed work and I'm aware of it. However I don't consider it being clean code. If nothing helps, I will fall back to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Param conversion is done with [`ParamConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverter.html)s. If you follow the stacktrace, you will see the [ParamConverters$DateProvider](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/ParamConverters.java#L245). The next call is the [`HttpDateFormat`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/HttpDateFormat.java) class which does the parsing.

If you look at the top of the class, you will see the date formats supported. These are standard HTTP data formats

```
/**
 * The date format pattern for RFC 1123.
 */
private static final String RFC1123_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
/**
 * The date format pattern for RFC 1036.
 */
private static final String RFC1036_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "EEEE, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss zzz";
/**
 * The date format pattern for ANSI C asctime().
 */
private static final String ANSI_C_ASCTIME_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy";
```

As far as I know or can tell, there is no configuration available where we can add to this list. The only other option is to write your own converter. For example

```
@Provider
public class DateParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    private final String format;

    public DateParamConverterProvider(String dateFormat) {
        this.format = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, 
                                              Type genericType, 
                                              Annotation[] annotations) {

        if (rawType != Date.class) { return null; }

        return (ParamConverter<T>) new ParamConverter<Date>() {

            @Override
            public Date fromString(String value) {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                try {
                    return formatter.parse(value);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new WebApplicationException("Bad formatted date", 400);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(Date date) { 
                return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date); 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is a complete test case using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)

```
public class DateParamTest extends JerseyTest {

    private static final String FORMAT = "MM-dd-yyyy";

    @Path("date")
    public static class DateResource {
        @GET
        public String get(@MatrixParam("since") Date date) {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT).format(date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(DateResource.class)
                .register(new DateParamConverterProvider(FORMAT));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_same_date_and_format() {
        final String date = "09-30-2015";
        Response response = target("date").matrixParam("since", date)
                .request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        String returnDate = response.readEntity(String.class);
        assertEquals(date, returnDate);
        System.out.println(returnDate);
    }
}
```

Here is the dependency for the test framework

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**See Also:**

- [Read another parameter within jersey's ParamConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27584161/2587435) for another example.
- [How to in-memory unit test Spring-Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28614846/2587435) for an example of using the test framework with a Spring-Jersey app.

Comment: Works well. Thanks! I was already looking at the ParamConverter, however I missed to register it. I added a not null check for the date parsing as well.